# Getting id of the view while resuing xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button in my main layout and onClick I'm reusing another xml layout following way:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_elemnt,
                            createLayout, false);
createLayout.addView(view, position);
position++;
```

where `single_elemnt` is the layout that will be added to the current main layout every time `add` button(present in main layout) is clicked.

`single_elemnt` has 2 views: a `textview` and an `edittext`. I'm using `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);` each time `add` is clicked.

But the problem is `tv` is always **referring to the first `textview`** even though I have placed `findViewById` code in onClick.

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <!-- some other views -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**onClick method in activity**

```
 View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_elemnt,
                                createLayout, false);
    createLayout.addView(view, position);
    position++;
tv = (TextView)profile.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("some text");
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: could you please post your code for `onClick()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find view in that particular view like this:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_elemnt,
                                createLayout, false);
createLayout.addView(view, position);
tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("some text");

position++;
```

Comment: How do I use this is keeping my question in mind. there is an another layout which I'm using. SO, instead of **view** in your ans, what should I use?

Comment: Where is the button on which onClick() you doing something.. can you post the button and its relevant code?